# DEM sources for arctic regions

Tags: dem

Are there any 90m DEMs out there for regions north of where the SRTM dataset ends? I looked at ASTER, but it seems to have a lot of unfilled voids, and it's important that the resolution matches the datasets I already have.

Comment: Though your area of interest likely extends beyond the State of Alaska, a good start would be the [Alaska state-wide DEM resources website](http://www.alaskamapped.org/dem), which I found through the [Geographic Information Network of Alaska (GINA)](http://www.gina.alaska.edu/data).

Comment: I'm most interested in Northern Europe right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erin,

You're best bet is GLSDEM which is 90m, global, and goes north beyond SRTM.

A description is here:

http://glcf.umd.edu/data/glsdem/description.shtml

Downloads are here:

http://glcf.umd.edu/data/glsdem/

Beyond that there is ICESat but it's laser altimeter data so there are gaps as well and the interpolated DEMs are 500m which doesn't meet your requirements:

http://nsidc.org/data/icesat/data.html

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at [Merit-DEM](http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yamadai/MERIT_DEM/), which fuses SRTM, viewfinderpanoramas, and a few other DEM sources. You can sign up quickly for an account and download the data as tiles.